# Saxon java methods cause a long blocked state in a multi-threaded application at high-load

Tags: java, multithreading, saxon

I am trying to embed Saxon HE into our web java application. Each request to an endpoint causes an XSLT transformation. I tried sending 100 concurrent requests at the same time to test Saxon. Using the java profiler, I found that some methods cause a long blocking state. Here is an example of the longest ones that take more than 90% of the time: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoeBb.png)

For comparison, the time spent in the Runnable state is 2.5 times less.

Is it possible to somehow solve the blocking state issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're seeing a common profiling effect where synchronized methods appear to be taking a high proportion of the total time, when actually what's happening is that they are much more likely to be sampled. The method `allocateDocumentNumber` is very unlikely to be causing much contention or taking a lot of time, but it could be distorting the profiling. If you have higher level of concurrency than the system can comfortably handle, then the scheduler will be looking for opportunities to pause one thread and give room for another, and these opportunities tend to coincide with calls on synchronized methods, even if those methods actually cause very little contention.

However, if you are hitting this method very heavily, it could suggest that you are creating a large number of temporary trees, which people often do unintentionally by writing code such as

```
<xsl:variable name="x">
  <xsl:value-of select="a/b/c"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

when they should be writing

```
<xsl:variable name="x" select="a/b/c"/>
```

I've seen a five-fold speed-up to a stylesheet when that error was fixed.

Every temporary tree needs to be allocated a unique document number for use if generate-id() is called. For some very trivial temporary trees comprising a single parentless node I think we allocate the document number lazily only if it's needed, but if the tree isn't completely trivial, the document number gets allocated on creation.

The call on `updateStatistics()` is another synchronised method, and is also associated with creation of temporary trees (it is used to learn what size to allocate for future trees, to minimise garbage collection overheads).

Of course, with any workload like this, allocating the right number of threads is the key to getting the right balance of throughput and response time. 100 threads is almost certainly larger than the optimum, unless you're using hardware with very high parallelism. I would expect the workload to be heavily CPU-bound, which means there is very little point in allocating more threads than you have CPUs available.

Comment: I have checked our code, we have a lot of variables that store tiny tree (but actually we need this, because we have a complex business logic in our xsl code). Most of these trees were created using call template or apply template constructs. I have tried replacing them with functions (xsl:function). And it seemed to give a result, but another blocking state appeared in another method: Expression.getSlotsUsed. https://imgur.io/rgyVrCA?r  Could you please clarify why this method is needed and is it possible to somehow avoid the problem with locks in this method?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the problem. These occasional synchronised methods aren't causing a performance problem. On the contrary, they are giving the scheduler an opportunity to share the CPU resource between the large number of threads you have created. You're not seeing a thread that is "blocked", you're seeing one that is ready to go as soon as the scheduler puts it at the front of the queue. A better way to increase response time and throughput would be to allocate fewer threads.